# Magento: How to load js file from lib directory?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to add a js file from lib directory and it's path is:

`rootdirectory/lib/myfolder/myjs.js`

I have added the below code to get that file in 1column.phtml:

```
<script src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseDir('lib') . '/myfolder/myjs.js'; ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But it is not loading the content with the following error below:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Though the file is present there.

Comment: please see the path of the script in the developer mode.is the path is the correct ?

Comment: Even if I type the path manually like mysite.com/lib/myfolder/myjs.js, even then it doesn't show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to move your file to a folder rootfolder/js/ and
in your layout (for example local.xml):

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>myfolder/myjs.js</script></action>
    </reference>
    ...
</default>
```

Answer (score 1):

**In .phtml file**
you need to call the js by following syntax

`<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('name.js');?>`

This will automatically gets located at js folder of your magento 
you will just have to name the js you want to load for current file to use it .